# finding min & max in an array with 3 increments

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, max, min

I need to find the max and min for every 3 elements of a data using java array.

For double data[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14} , what is the max and min in every 3 elements? In other words, what is the max and min for {1,2,3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, etc.

I have the following method, but it is not getting the right results.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i+=3) {

        for (int r = i; r < i + 3 && r < data.length; r++) {

            if (data[r] < lowest) { lowest = data[r]; }
            if (data[r] > highest) { highest = data[r]; }

        }

        lowest = highest;
        highest = 0;
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Why do you do `lowest = highest`? Do you mean to do this after setting `highest = 0` to reset both lowest and highest?

Comment: Also, is the data guarenteed to be sorted (like in your example)?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
int[] data = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
int processed = 0;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] < min) {
        min = data[i];
    }
    if (data[i] > max) {
        max = data[i];
    }

    processed++;
    if (processed == 3) {
        System.out.println("Min is: " + min);
        System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
        System.out.println("--------");

        processed = 0;
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Min is: 1
Max is: 3
--------
Min is: 4
Max is: 6
--------
Min is: 7
Max is: 9
--------
Min is: 10
Max is: 12
--------
```

It's unclear what to do with the numbers 13 and 14, as they don't form a block of 3, but I guess you get the idea of the algorithm.

Comment: @GeorgeWang maybe approve my answer? :)